Why does DiagonalizableMatrixQ give different answers when Simplify or FullSimplify is applied to a 4x4 matrix, consisting of complex trig. functions?
NOTE: I HAVE CLEANED UP THIS DISCUSSION TO MAKE THINGS MORE TRANSPARENT:
I am using Mathematica version 12.1. I have a 4x4 matrix called matrixA[x, y], which contains elements that are complex trigonometric functions where
matrixA[x_,y_] = numerator[x, y]/denominator[x, y]

and where
a) numerator[x, y]  is a 4 by 4 matrix, which contains elements that are complex trigonometric functions.
b) denominator[x, y] is the trace of numerator[x, y]
CASE 1:
I run tests on matrixA[x,y], leaving x and y in symbolic form.
I check to see if matrixA[x,y] is diagonalizable by running
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[matrixA[x,y]]

Mathematica returns False.
CASE 2:
I apply the Simplify function to matrixA[x,y] and assign the result to matrixB[x,y]:
matrixB[x_,y_] = Simplify[matrixA[x,y]]

To ensure that the simplification hasn't altered the matrix, I compare matrixB[x,y] with matrixA[x,y] using:
matrixB[x,y] == matrixA[x,y]

This check returns True, confirming that both matrices are still the same. However, when I check the diagonalizability of matrixB[x,y] using:
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[matrixB[x,y]]

Surprisingly, Mathematica returns True, in this case?!
CASE 3:
I apply the full simplify function to matrixA[x,y] using FullSimplify and assign the result to matrixC[x,y]:
matrixC[x_,y_] = FullSimplify[matrixA[x, y]]

To ensure that the full simplification hasn't altered the matrix, I compare matrixC[x,y] with matrixA[x,y] using:
matrixC[x,y] == matrixA[x,y]

This check returns True, confirming that both matrices are still the same.
However, when I check the diagonalizability of matrixC[x,y] using:
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[matrixC[x,y]]
Surprisingly, Mathematica returns False.
As far as I can tell, the only difference between matrixA[x, y] and matrixC[x, y] is the replacement of trigonometric expressions like Cos[theta] + iSin[theta] and Cos[theta] - iSin[theta] with their equivalent exponential forms.
CASE 4:
If I run Simplify function separately to the numerator and denominator and assign this to matrixD[x,y]such that
matrixD[x_, y_] = Simplify[numerator[x, y]]/Simplify[denominator[x, y]]

and check if matrixD[x, y] is diagonalizable such that
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[matrixD[x, y]]
Mathematica returns False. This indicates that applying the Simplify function to the entire fraction maintains the diagonalizability of the matrix. However, when Simplify is applied separately to the numerator and the denominator, the matrix no longer remains diagonalizable.
However, if I check if matrixD[x, y] is still equal to matrixA[x, y] such that
matrixD[x, y] == matrixA[x, y]

Mathematica returns True.

NUMERICAL EVALUATION TEST

Below is a script that evaluates matrixA before checking if it is diagonalizable. x ranges between 0 and pi, whereas y ranges from 0 to 2pi. You can adjust the step size for the evaluation by changing the value of the variable called step (given in degrees).

The script tracks Non-Diagonalizable Cases: Uses an empty list, nonDiagonalizableCases, to track (x, y) pairs where the matrix is not diagonalizable.

Loops through Values: The Do loop iterates through possible values of x and y, evaluating each matrix at these points. If a matrix is not diagonalizable, the coordinates are added to nonDiagonalizableCases.

Result Summary: After the loop, it checks the length of nonDiagonalizableCases. If it’s zero, it confirms all matrices were diagonalizable; otherwise, it lists the problematic (x, y) pairs. This approach gives you a direct report on the diagonalizability across the specified range and explicitly identifies any exceptions.


FINDINGS:
The script returns ```All matrices are diagonalizable.''' for the following cases:
CASE 1: (numerical evaluation of matrixA)
When
matrixA[x_, y_] = numerator[x,y]/denominator[x,y];

and I evaluate for x and y then test for diagonalization Mathematica now returns True. (Note that when x and y are in symbolic form, Mathematica returned False in this case.)
CASE 2: (numerical evaluation of matrixB)
When
matrixB[x_, y_] = Simplify[matrixA[x, y]]

and I evaluate for x and y then test for diagonalization Mathematica now returns True. (Note that when x and y are in symbolic form, Mathematica also returned True in this case.)
CASE 3: (numerical evaluation of matrixC[x, y])
When
matrixC[x_, y_] = FullSimplify[matrixA[x, y]]

now also returns True when I evaluate for x and y then test for diagonalization. (Note that when x and y are in symbolic form, Mathematica returns False in this case.)
CASE 4: (numerical evaluation of matrixD[x, y])
When
matrixD[x_, y_] = Simplify[numerator[x,y]]/Simplify[denominator[x,y]]

now also returns True when I evaluate for x and y then test for diagonalization. (Note that when x and y are in symbolic form, Mathematica returns False in this case.)

CONCLUSION THUS FAR.

It seems Mathematica gives consistent results if matrixA is evaluated first before checking if it is diagonalizable.
Why do I not obtain the same consistency when matrixA[x,y] is left in symbolic form?
Below is the script that defines matrixA and evaluates it under the different cases specified above.
Clear["Global`*"];
ClearSystemCache[];

Ep[x_] := 1/(2 - Cos[x])

t11[x_] := (Cos[x] (Cos[x]^2 - 3 Cos[x] + 3) - 3)/(Cos[x] - 2)

t12[x_] := Sin[x]^2

t33[x_] := 2 Cos[x]

t44[x_] := (Cos[x] (Cos[x] (4 - Cos[x]) - 5))/(Cos[x] - 2)

Sp[x_, y_] := ({
   {t11[x], t12[x], 0, 0},
   {-t12[x] Cos[2 y], -(2 - t12[x]) Cos[2 y], t33[x] Sin[2 y], 0},
   {t12[x] Sin[2 y], (2 - t12[x]) Sin[2 y], t33[x] Cos[2 y], 0},
   {0, 0, 0, t44[x]}
  })

sigma[i_, j_] := KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[i], PauliMatrix[j]]
numerator[x_, y_] = 1/4 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 
        1\), \(4\)]\(Sp[x, y]\)[\([i, j]\)]*sigma[i - 1, j - 1])\)\);
denominator[x_, y_] = Tr[numerator[x, y]];

(*matrixA[x_,y_]=numerator[x,y]/denominator[x,y];*)

(*matrixA[x_,y_]=Simplify[numerator[x,y]/denominator[x,y]];*)

(*matrixA[x_,y_]=FullSimplify[numerator[x,y]/denominator[x,y]];*)

matrixA[x_, y_] = Simplify[numerator[x, y]]/
  Simplify[denominator[x, y]];

(*Set the step size in radians equivalent to step degrees*)
step = 1;
stepSizeRadians = step*Pi/180;

(*Initialize an empty list to store cases where the matrix is not \
diagonalizable*)
nonDiagonalizableCases = {};

(*Iterate over the range of x and y*)
Do[If[DiagonalizableMatrixQ[matrixA[x, y]] === False,
   (*If the matrix is not diagonalizable,append this case to the list*)
   AppendTo[nonDiagonalizableCases, {x, y}]], {x, 0, Pi, 
   stepSizeRadians}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, stepSizeRadians}];

(*Check if there were any non-diagonalizable cases*)
If[Length[nonDiagonalizableCases] == 0,
 Print["All matrices are diagonalizable."], 
 Print["Matrices are not diagonalizable at the following values of x \
and y:"];
 Print[nonDiagonalizableCases]]


Please edit the question and include the code for your matrixA instead of a screenshot.

Thank you for the response. I have done what you asked.

In version 14.1 I have different results for matrixA and matrixB. I do replicate the False for matrixB. Which is not correct,

Filed as a bug.

I have version 12.1. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Mathematica hoping the problem would go away but unfortunately it has not.  Also when I run SameQ[matrixA, matrixB], this returns False, when it should return True

@QuantumKid, no, SameQ tests for the exact structural identity between expressions, so it's okay to return False in your case.

@Domen. I see. Thank you for that.

I created a brand new file to eliminate the possibility of file corruption affecting the results, but unfortunately, the issue persists. I have included the code that generates matrixA and conducted additional tests. For details on these tests and the outcomes, please refer to the "UPDATE" section above.

@DanielLichtblau How did you come to the conclusion that there is a bug? I guess there are some hidden zeros that in one case cancel out and in another not thus producing different results. But with such a complex matrix and trigonometric functions in it I would not consider it to be a bug. With trigonometric functions it is easy to get expression that is zero but hard to simplify it to zero.

The eigenvalues of the iriginal matrix and the full- simplified version agree at a random substitution point (as one would expect) and are distinct. By that criterion both are diagonalizable (even neglecting that they arise from the same matrix).

It appears that Mathematica provides consistent results when matrixA is evaluated prior to checking its diagonalizability. For detailed findings and the testing code, please see the 'SECOND UPDATE' section.

@DanielLichtblau If you do not write @my_nick in your comment I am not aware I got any response. If random substitution gave different result then I would call it a bug. But for symbolic input I am not convinced it is a bug. Because for such a big expression with lots of trigonometric functions it is not trivial to factor out possible zero factor in the expression. A simple such "hidden zero" is 1 - Cos[x]^2 - Sin[x]^2 but there could much much more convoluted ones that are hard to factor out of complicated expressions. But maybe I am wrong.

@azerbajdzan I've just ran a test (see second update for more detail) where I evaluate matrixA before checking if it is diagonalizable. In all iterations,  matrixA remains diagonalizable, provided that matrixA is evaluated first. Could these consistent results suggest to you a potential bug in the software?

@azerbajdzan I am hard pressed to imagine how my test would get that wrong (read: it’s not getting it wrong).
